# How to set gulp-watch options

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

On the gulp-watch page (https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch) it shows the gulp-watch can be configured via the options.

This is how I use the gulp-watch:

```
watch('/public/app/**/*.html',function(){
    runSequence('templatecache');
}).on('error', standardHandler);
```

So, how I can put the option? Do I need to put options on every watch? Is there any global options?

Comment: Looks like options are the second argument to `watch` as an object. If you'd like to make them global, you'll probably want to have a general configuration which you pass to each `watch` statement and modify as needed.

Comment: @J4G It would be nice if you could show the example for better understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options are the second argument to `watch`.

`watch('/public/app/**/*.html', {someOptionHere: true}, function () {});`

There's no global configuration, and I'd recommend placing each options object individually, but if you'd like you can create a shared config object and then extend each one as necessary.

```
var extend = require('util')._extend;
var globalOptions = {
   someOption: true
}

watch('/somePath/*.js', extend(globalOptions, { another: 'option' }), function () {})
```